# find the document from sub array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents that look like this:

```
"awards" : {
    "oscars" : [
        {"award": "bestAnimatedFeature", "result": "won"},
        {"award": "bestMusic", "result": "won"},
        {"award": "bestPicture", "result": "nominated"},
        {"award": "bestSoundEditing", "result": "nominated"},
        {"award": "bestScreenplay", "result": "nominated"}
    ],
    "wins" : 56,
    "nominations" : 86,
    "text" : "Won 2 Oscars. Another 56 wins and 86 nominations."
}
```

What query document would we use in a `find()` command to return all movies in the `my_collection` collection that either won or were nominated for best picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to specify an exact match on the embedded document and use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator to select those documents that *won or were nominated for best picture*

You shouldn't use the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or) operator here because it will perform a collection scan if not  all the clauses are supported by indexes as mention in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes).

```js
db.my_collection.find({ 
    'awards.oscars.award': 'bestPicture', 
    'awards.oscars.result': { '$in': [ 'won', 'nominated' ] } 
} )
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MongoDB Query documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/), you can match a field in an embedded document within an array by concatenating its name to the name of the array like so:

```
db.my_collection.find(
  {
    'awards.oscars.award': 'bestPicture',
    $or: [
      { 'awards.oscars.result': 'won' },
      { 'awards.oscars.result': 'nominated' }
    ]
  }
)
```